# How can I permanently set up resolv.conf in GCP VMs with nameservers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nameservers

I would like to access some URLs through Curl on my GCP VM which isn't exposed to external traffic(It doesn't have an external IP too). I would like to know how can I set this up with nameservers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Any help here is highly appreciated.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - /etc/resolv.conf is overwritten every hour on GCP VMs (during DHCP renew).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add name servers for most Linux operating systems on Google Cloud, modify `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.

For example, add the following line:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

Do not forget the trailing semicolon.

Comment: You're correct, but according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#resolv.conf), this is only certain for Debian.

Comment: I wonder if the OP can comment on what GCP VM OS they are targetting?

Comment: @MartinZeitler - This is a good example of "invest in your question to receive the best answers".

Comment: @JohnHanley, thank you for the answer. I did the same in dhcp conf but I just realized I missed the semicolon. It worked after adding it.

Is there any other way to set this up at Zone/instance metadata level so that I don't need to go into each instance and set it up if I have more than some 50 VMs?

Comment: @RaviKMahankali You could create a shell script (sed or cat) to modify dhclient.conf. Then use the CLI (gcloud) to loop thru each instance executing the script using SSH.